# Core data taking time to insert records with fetching entity & set as relationship

Tags: ios, swift, performance, relationship

I have 2 entities: Components & SurveyReadingWeb that have a one-to-many relationship.
I have saved Components data in core data database; but while saving SurveyReadingWeb -- in a for loop -- I have to fetch Components data entity by passing component id and setting the surveyreadings isComponentexists relationship, like in the code below for 8000 records. This process is taking too much time, nearly 7 minutes.  How can I reduce the time?

```
for item in items {
            autoIncrementId = autoIncrementId + 1
            print("reading items parsed:- \(item.SurveyReadingId), \(autoIncrementId)")

            let reading : SurveyReadingWeb? = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: Constants.EntityNames.kSURVEYREADINGWEB, into: self.managedContext) as? SurveyReadingWeb
            reading?.surveyId1 = Int32(autoIncrementId)
            reading?.surveyId = Int32(item.SurveyId) ?? 0
            reading?.readingData = item.CH4
            reading?.surveyDateTime = item.SurveyReadingDateTime
            reading?.latitude = item.Latitude
            reading?.longitude = item.Longitude
            reading?.serialNumber = item.SerialNumber
            reading?.descriptionText = item.Description
            reading?.componentName = item.Description
            reading?.componentId = Int32(item.ComponentId) ?? 0
            reading?.readingTypeId = Int32(item.ReadingTypeID) ?? 0
            reading?.readingTypeDetails = item.ReadingTypeDetails

            reading?.currentLatitude = item.CurrentLatitude
            reading?.currentLongitude = item.CurrentLongitude
            reading?.hdop = item.HDOP
            reading?.vdop = item.VDOP
            reading?.componentDistance = item.ComponentDistance
            reading?.facilityId = Int32(item.ProjectId) ?? 0
            reading?.posted = 1
            reading?.readyToSync = 1

            reading?.isComponentExists = DatabaseManager.sharedManager.getCompNameFromID(compID: Int32(item.ComponentId) ?? 0)
        }
        saveContext()


func getCompNameFromID(compID : Int32) -> Components? {
    var component : Components? = nil
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Components> = Components.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "componentId == %ld", compID)

    do {
        let searchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        component =  (searchResults.first) ?? nil
    } catch {
    }
    return component ?? nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time dramatically if you add an `NSCache` instance to cache `compID:Components` key value pairs.

In `getCompNameFromID` check if the `compID` exists in the cache. If yes get the value from the cache (very fast), if not fetch the record and save it for the `compID` in the cache.

And use the convenient `SurveyReadingWeb(context:` initializer to get rid of all the ugly question marks, however the performance benefit is rather tiny.

Comment: Can you please provide code for adding NSCache?I have added this way .Will it work ?Will it caches all componentid or override the values ?
let cache = NSCache<NSString, Components>()
cache.setValue(component?.componentId, forKey: "CachedComponent")

Comment: `NSCache` works like a dictionary. A key is supposed to be the identifier (`componentId`), the corresponding value the `component` object. Set a key-value pair with `setObject(_:forKey:)` and read it with `object(forKey:)`. Don't use the KVC methods.