# core data taking time to check whether data is present or not against particular id in for loop of 1000

Tags: ios, swift, performance

I have 2 entities: `Components` and `SurveyWebReadings`. In SurveyWebReadings we have readings against component id. In Component entity we have all components with their id, area, subarea, facilityid attributes.

Now we want to check whether for particular Component id is there readings available or not in SurveyWebReading table. For that we get componentIds array from Component entity using predicates for area & subarea & facilityId. We get the maximum componentId array of count 1200. When we check whether reading is available or not against that ids in for loop of 1200 ids, application get freezes.

Any other way of checking whether reading present or not against that component id except realationship?

Below are the functions for fetching component ids & checking whether reading present or not against that component id & the code we called it in for loop:

```
func fetchComponentArrayByAreaSubarea(facilityID: Int32, area: String, subArea: String) -> [Components] {

        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Components> = Components.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "faclityID == %ld AND area == %@ AND subarea == %@", facilityID, area, subArea)
        //let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "componentId", ascending: true)
        //fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "iD", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        do {
            let searchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return searchResults
        } catch {
        }
        return []        
}
```

```
func checkIfCompExistInReadingTable(surveyId: Int32, compId: Int32) -> Bool {

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<SurveyReadingWeb>(entityName: "SurveyReadingWeb")
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "surveyId == %ld AND componentId == %ld AND readyToSync == 1", surveyId, compId)
            fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
            var results: [SurveyReadingWeb] = []

            do {
                results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            }
            catch {
            }
            return results.count > 0
}
```

```
self.arrCompValues = DatabaseManager.sharedManager.fetchComponentArrayByAreaSubarea(facilityID: self.currentSurvey?.facilityId ?? 0, area: self.lblDisplaySelectedArea.text ?? "", subArea: self.lblDisplaySelectedSubarea.text ?? "")

for component in arrCompValues {
            let comp = component as? Components

            let ifCompExist: Bool = DatabaseManager.sharedManager.checkIfCompExistInReadingTable(surveyId: currentSurvey?.surveyId ?? 0, compId: comp?.componentId ?? 0)
            if ifCompExist {
                print("is reading ava:- \(ifCompExist), ")
                arrCompReadingDone1.append(comp!)
            }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but in the second function, instead of fetching the elements, you could directly count them: 'results = try managedContext.count(for: fetchRequest)'

Comment: You need to understand that CoreData isn't a database. It is an object persistence system. Any time you find yourself performing a query by object Id you are probably doing something wrong.  Each reading should have a to-one relationship to its component. You can then use a set of predicates that return the matching readings

Comment: @Paulw11 We tried adding to many relationship as well.But it is also taking time to set relationship .At start we sync all components & saved in core data .After that we call to syncReadings,while inserting readings in the database we are setting relationship for component,for that we need to fetch components entity from database & set it to relationship.For 8000 readings it is taking near about 7 minutes.Kindly refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087792/core-data-taking-time-to-insert-records-with-fetching-entity-set-as-relationsh)

Comment: Again, in that code I see you are using record ids and fetching records by id. If you treat Core Data as a relational database you are going to have a bad time. Even if your source data has ids you can use the cache id to save the component object and then you simply assign that component entry to the reference field in the reading.

Comment: If you are simply going to store the reference rather than the id property then you can use a managedObjectIDResultType for your query which will be faster.

Comment: @Paulw11 can we set NSManagedObjectID to relationship ?

Comment: Yes, that's what relationship properties hold.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please provide me code for setting NSMnagedObjectID to relationship,
       ,it is giving me  error as "Cannot assign value of type 'NSManagedObjectID' to type 'Components'"

Comment: My mistake.  You need to call [objectwithID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506197-objectwithid?language=objc) to ge the actual object.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have used object(with:) function to get actual object,but when I set it to relationship & prints the data it is coming as <fault>. I have posted it as different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169290/relationships-entitys-data-is-fault).Please refer & reply.