# Relationship's entity's data is <fault>

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, fault

I have asked reference question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087792/core-data-taking-time-to-insert-records-with-fetching-entity-set-as-relationsh).I got answer using NSMangedObjectID.Now I have used below function to get Component entity from its componentID.As in the API response of SyncSurveyWebReadings,I only get componentId,I need to fetch Component entity & set as relationship.Now time taking issue is not there.But may be relationship is not getting set.When I print the relationship object I got,

```
Optional<Array<SurveyReadingWeb>>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    - 0 : <GazSurvey_Dev.SurveyReadingWeb: 0x282e0c8c0> (entity: SurveyReadingWeb; id: 0xf496ed8ab8c8dfd6 <x-coredata://3A27D5DB-BFBC-4005-BA69-59CB5C392617/SurveyReadingWeb/p4000> ; data: <fault>)

func getComponentFromID(compID : Int32) -> Components? {
    var component :Components? = nil
    var objectId : NSManagedObjectID? = nil

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObjectID>(entityName: "Components")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "componentId == %ld", compID)


    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.managedObjectIDResultType


    do {
        objectId = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first

        if objectId != nil {
            component =  managedContext.object(with: objectId!) as? Components
        }
    }
    catch {
    }

    return component
}
```

Comment: One of these will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcore-data%5D+fault the top few look promising. 'Fault' is a placeholder for the relationships data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CoreData relationship fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault)